# Healing magic in Harry Potter universe?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

I've seen students get injured, breaking their bones, and not a single instant healing spell... not even faster regain of health.

In the wiki they say that there is one, but the question remains; when the Battle for Hogwarts starts, a lot (literally hundreds) of deaths would have been prevented by using healing magic... If anyone didn't die in 1 hit, they would have an inexhaustible army...

Quite literally if I didn't search the wiki, I still wouldn't be convinced.

Can anyone tell me if there is actually a place in the movies where healing magic is used?

Comment: In which movie? All of them?

Comment: I talk about deathly hallows, but if you want you can say that there isn't a single instance of healing magic being used anywhere in any move

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Healing_spell

Comment: [This one](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Brackium_Emendo) was used in the films

Comment: Can't be bothered to turn this into a proper answer but there is no one-sized-fits-all Healing Spell. There's Dittany which heals (at least superficially) most minor ailments. Other spells and potions combat specific injuries (e.g. episkey). There are Healers and people like Madame Pomfrey but no magic which can deliver people from death. Indeed, accepting death is a pretty big part of the whole series.

Comment: It's enough I guess. I didn't see healing spells at all, and they were used so subtly, that I forgot about their existence... it's like Rowling wanted to hide it xD

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Cleared up some of my questions, and answered this one :D

Comment: Sounds like you play *Clash of Clans* a lot... Just put the healers behind Giants and enjoy the show unless the enemy has Inferno Tower.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like specialized skills are needed for magical healing. Even Dumbledore would take injured folks to Poppy Pomfrey.

> “Get Madam Pomfrey,” whispered Dumbledore, and Professor McGonagall hurried past the end of Harry’s bed out of sight. Harry lay quite still, pretending to be asleep. He heard urgent voices, and then Professor McGonagall swept back into view, closely followed by Madam Pomfrey, who was pulling a cardigan on over her nightdress. He heard a sharp intake of breath.
>
> “What happened?” Madam Pomfrey whispered to Dumbledore, bending over the statue on the bed.
>
> “Another attack,” said Dumbledore. “Minerva found him on the stairs.”
>
> <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and The Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 10, The Rogue Bludger**</sup></sub>

**Not all issues can be solved by wand work.**

> Hermione and Madam Pomfrey came around the curtain. Madam Pomfrey was holding a large bottle of something labeled Skele-Gro.
>
> “You’re in for a rough night,” she said, pouring out a steaming beakerful and handing it to him. “Regrowing bones is a nasty business.”
>
> <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and The Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 10, The Rogue Bludger**</sup></sub>

**Some injuries can be fixed in minutes**

> “How’s your arm?” said Harry.
>
> “Fine,” said Neville, showing them. “Madam Pomfrey mended it in about a minute.”
>
> <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, Chapter 9, The Midnight Duel**</sup></sub>

But based on the injury type, it can take anywhere from few minutes to many days of rest for injured people to recovery.

**Some take days:**

> “How long have I been in here?”
>
> “Three days. Mr. Ronald Weasley and Miss Granger will be most relieved you have come round, they have been extremely worried.”
>
> <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, Chapter 17, The Man With Two Faces**</sup></sub>

But generally, magical injuries take longer to recover from. Mr. Weasley  spent days in St Mungo's Hospital for Magical Maladies and Injuries because his bleeding would not stop.

> “Why can't they take them off, Dad?" asked Fred.
>
> "Well, I start bleeding like mad every time they try," said Mr Weasley cheerfully, reaching across for his wand, which lay on his bedside cabinet, and waving it so that six extra chairs appeared at his bedside to seat them all. "It seems there was some rather unusual kind of poison in that snake's fangs that keeps wounds open. They're sure they'll find an antidote, though; they say they've had much worse cases than mine, and in the meantime I just have to keep taking a Blood-Replenishing Potion every hour.”
>
> <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix Stone, Chapter 22, St Mungo's Hospital for Magical Maladies and Injuries**</sup></sub>

Since lots of injuries caused during the Battle of Hogwarts would have been magically induced, it is hard to say how many people could have been saved. But I don't think Medical help were lacking. It's just that too many folks were getting injured.

**Now, we have time for one video!**

The famous Skele Gro scene:

Comment: Well said. I have often thought that healers are probably the most powerful wizards/witches in the HP universe - they deal with (and often fix) the most bizarre magic, much of it being truly one-of-a-kind. I think Madame Pomfrey and/or the St Mungos staff should have been giving instruction at Hogwarts as well, but (as in real life) they are almost entirely out of sight until their services are needed.

Comment: What about Vulnera Sanentur? It was used by Snape to heal Draco after Harry's Sectumsempra in "The Half-Blood Prince" movie.

Answer (score 0):

Luna fixes Harry’s nose after he tries to spy on Malfoy on the train in *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*.

> **Episkey!**

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to specify the book or movie you're referring to, and if possible, add a relevant quote or video clip from said book or movie.